# how to merge two arrays (array 1d and array 2d object) into a array using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am looking for best ways of doing this. I have two arrays (array 1d and array 2d object):

```
let keys = [11, 12];
let values = [
[
   { name: '1', link: '1', history: '1' },
   { name: '2', link: '2', history: '2' }
 ],
 [
   { name: '3', link: '3', history: '3' },
   { name: '4', link: '4', history: '4' }
 ]
]
```

The end result I want is an array of map:

```
[
   { name: '1', link: '1', history: '1' , q : 11},
   { name: '2', link: '2', history: '2' , q : 11},
   { name: '3', link: '3', history: '3' , q : 12},
   { name: '4', link: '4', history: '4' , q : 12}
]
```

How do I do it the most efficient/clean way using lodash? Thanks!

> This code without lodash :

```js
let arr = [];
let keys = [ 29, 30 ]
let values = [
  [
    { name: '1', link: '1', history: '1' },
    { name: '2', link: '2', history: '2' }
  ],
  [
    { name: '3', link: '3', history: '3' },
    { name: '4', link: '4', history: '4' }
  ]
]
for (let j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < values[j].length; i++) {
    arr.push({ ...values[j][i], q: keys[j] });
  }
}
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: why do you need lodash?

Comment: I'm worried about the time if so much information.

Comment: wait pls i think i ask wrong .

Comment: @NinaScholz I edit it .

Comment: How did you decide to map which keys go to which array?

Comment: @bharadhwaj new array , wait pls , i try write without lodash

Comment: @bharadhwaj  example in post , i edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply just use _.map

```js
let keys = [11, 12];
let values = [[{"name":"1","link":"1","history":"1"},{"name":"2","link":"2","history":"2"}],[{"name":"3","link":"3","history":"3"},{"name":"4","link":"4","history":"4"}]]
console.log(_.map(values, (v, i) => _.map(v, o => (o.q = keys[i], o))))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.core.js"></script>
```

or without lodash which is pretty much the same syntax wise

```js
let keys = [11, 12];
let values = [[{"name":"1","link":"1","history":"1"},{"name":"2","link":"2","history":"2"}],[{"name":"3","link":"3","history":"3"},{"name":"4","link":"4","history":"4"}]]
console.log(values.map((v, i) => v.map(o => (o.q = keys[i], o))))
```

edit: I forgot that the resulting array has to be 1D.
 - The lodash variation needs to get some _.flatten over the result
 - The native js needs a .flat()

Lastly one may use lodash/fp to get some chaining style

```js
let keys = [11, 12];
let values = [[{"name":"1","link":"1","history":"1"},{"name":"2","link":"2","history":"2"}],[{"name":"3","link":"3","history":"3"},{"name":"4","link":"4","history":"4"}]]

console.log(
  _.flow(
    // we need to use entries to get the index of fp.map
    _.entries,
    // for each array
    _.map(([i, v]) => 
      // foreach "history" of the array
      _.map(
        // merge the key to the current "history"
        _.merge({ q: keys[i] }), v)
      ),
    _.flatten
  )(values)
)

console.log(
  _.flow(
    // or its variant
    _.map.convert({ cap: false })((v,i) => _.map(_.merge({ q: keys[i] }), v)),
    _.flatten
  )(values)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have not been precise enough but the resulting array is [[],[]], if you want a 1d array you may just use flat() at the end @sir air

Comment: i using _.flatMap(result) , i work for me. thanks again @grodzi

Comment: you are welcome @sir air
I am also adding an example using lodash/fp which people seem to like to work with (I do not share this opinion but this may be useful to you)

Answer (score 1):

Not a lodash solution, but a universal approach for more arrays with objects for merging to get a cartesian product.

```js
let keys = [11, 12],
    values = [[{ name: '1', link: '1', history: '1' }, { name: '2', link: '2', history: '2' }], [{ name: '3', link: '3', history: '3' }, { name: '4', link: '4', history: '4' }]],
    data = [
        values.flat(),
        keys.map(q => ({ q }))
    ],
    result = data.reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => ({ ...v, ...w }))), []));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.flatMap()` (or lodash's `_.flatMap()`) to iterate the values, and then map the sub-arrays, and add the respective key:

```js
const keys = [11, 12];
const values = [[{"name":"1","link":"1","history":"1"},{"name":"2","link":"2","history":"2"}],[{"name":"3","link":"3","history":"3"},{"name":"4","link":"4","history":"4"}]]

const result = values.flatMap((arr, i) => 
  arr.map(o => ({ ...o, q: keys[i] }))
)

console.log(result)
```